# A question about time taken in numpy array assignment with and without slices

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

I was trying to understand the assignment of values to slices of `NumPy` arrays. In particular, if sliced assignments are slower than 'less sliced' assignments.

Example:

```
a[0,:10] = 5
vs
a[0:1,:10] = 5
```

This inadvertently landed me on a situation where I was trying to compare

```
a[:,:] = a[:,:] + 1
vs
a = a + 1
```

I failed to understand the results

**Case 1: The array creation is outside the loop**

```
b=np.arange(100000000).reshape(-1,100).astype(np.float64)
out = []
for i in range(50):
    ti1 = time.time()
    b = b+1
    tf1 = time.time()
    tt1 = tf1 - ti1

    ti2 = time.time()
    b[:,:] = b[:,:]+1
    tf2 = time.time()
    tt2 = tf2 - ti2
    out.append((tt1,tt2))
print(len(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] > x[1], out))))
```

output:

```
22
```

**CASE 2 : The array creation is inside the loop**

```
out1 = []
for i in range(50):
    b=np.arange(100000000).reshape(-1,100).astype(np.float64)
    ti1 = time.time()
    b = b+1
    tf1 = time.time()
    tt1 = tf1 - ti1

    ti2 = time.time()
    b[:,:] = b[:,:]+1
    tf2 = time.time()
    tt2 = tf2 - ti2
    out1.append((tt1,tt2))
print(len(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] > x[1], out1))))
```

output:

```
0
```

It seems that the first time after the creation of the array, `b = b + 1` necessarily takes less time than `b[:,:] = b[:,:] + 1`

- Why is it so?
- What changes after `b = b + 1` and `b[:,:] = b[:,:] + 1` have been run once that they both now take up the same amount of time approximately?